# How to add extra attributies to vertices (that already have attributes) in a graph in Spark Graphx Scala?

Tags: scala, twitter, graph, apache-spark, spark-graphx

***Situation:***

I have constructed a graph in Spark (in scala) based on some tweeter data like so:

- each vertex has a tweet id(Long) and the body of the tweet(String)
- each edge connects the source tweet to the retweet

The way I've done it is to create a graph from the file of edges:

```
val followerGraph = GraphLoader.edgeListFile(sc, "C:\\Users\\...\\tweetGraphEdgesData.txt")
```

and then add the attributes to each vertex using outerJoinVertices

```
   val graph = followerGraph.outerJoinVertices(verticesData){
    case(uid,deg,Some(attrList))=>attrList
    case(uid,deg,None)=> Array.empty[String]
   }
```

***Problem:***

> Now I want to attach to each vertex the number of edges it is connected to  (which basically means how many times it has been re-tweeted). How can I do  this?

Comment: http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/graphx-programming-guide.html#property-operators There is just what you want given as example.

Answer (score 0):

Simply join the vertices with the number of outgoing edges

```
graph.vertices.leftOuterJoin(graph.outDegrees)
```